# method undefined?

Tags: ruby

I am new to ruby. I tried to do a simple method(with parameter) call.

```
class MeowEncoder
    def method(c)
        puts c
        end
    end

print "please enter the thing you want"
s = gets.chomp()
MeowEncoder.method(s)
```

It is only passing parameter and prints it out. But the terminal keep giving me errors like

```
:MeowEncoder.rb:9: undefined method `toBinary' for MeowEncoder:Class (NoMethodError)
```

what is going on here?

I made some enhancement.

```
class MeowEncoder
        def encode(n)
            toBianry(?n)
            puts ""
        end

        def toBinary(n)
            if n < 2
                print n
            else
                toBinary(n / 2)
                print n % 2
            end
        end
    end

    o = MeowEncoder.new


    print "please enter the thing you want: "
    s = gets.chomp()
    s.each_char{|c| o.encode(c)} #this doesn't work
    o.toBinary(212)  # this works
```

I made some enhancement here. I try to convert a char to its ASCII value then to its binary form. I can made the single  toBinary works. But the Encode method also gave me same error. What happened?

Comment: Write a script with a single line: `puts self` and you will get "main" when you run it. Make that line `puts self.class` and you will get "Object".

Comment: It looks like you used `toBianry` in your `encode` method. Is this an error in your script or in your post?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You defined an instance method, but you're trying to call it on a class object. Try this:

```
MeowEncoder.new.method(s)
```

Also, `method` is a **bad** name for a method. It will cause a [name clash](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html#method-i-method).

Comment: Hey thank you for that. I made some enhancement. But error occurs again. Mind helping me?

Comment: you have a typo - `toBianry`

Comment: Never mind, I know what is going on now. Just a typo.. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

To expand on Sergio's answer, if you actually wanted the method defined on the class, there are several ways to accomplish that, but the most straightforward is to prepend the method definition with `self` like so:

```
def self.method(c)
  puts c
end
```

That will allow you to invoke the method the way you are currently.

The reason this works is, in the context of defining the method, `self` is set to the `MeowEncoder` class. It's equivalent to saying:

```
def MeowEncoder.method(c)
  puts c
end
```

This is actually another valid way to declare class methods, but using `self` is better practice, as refactoring becomes easier if you ever change the name of your class.

Comment: Thank you very much for this extra knowledge

Answer (score 0):

Instead of **each_char** use **each_byte** and no need of encode method.

```
s.each_byte{|c| o.toBinary(c)}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Book (title, author)
Author (pseudonym, first_name, last_name)
Book_catalog => collection of books
    methods
        add_book(book)
        remove_book(book)
        ​borrow_book(borrower, book)  => voeg boek toe aan borrower.books_borrowed
        return_book(borrower, book) => verwijder boek uit borrower.books_borrowed
        book_available?(book)
        search(title) => geeft gevonden book-object terug (anders nil)
Book_borrowing
    book (read-only), date_of_borrowing (read-only), date_of_return (read-only)
    borrow_book(book_to_borrow) : @date_of_borrowing = systeem-datum+uur
    return_book(book_to_return) : @date_of_return = systeem-datum+uur
Borrower
    member_nbr, first_name, last_name, books_borrowed = collection of Book_borrowing
    has_book_by_title(title) => geeft true of false terug
    has_book(book) => geeft true of false terug
Person(first_name, last_name)
```